# onDataChange() in Firebase getting triggered multiple times

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase the onDataChange() function gets called multiple times, after some  searching I found out that it would be called the number of times the listener is getting attached. But I have attached the listener multiple times since I need the different queries and fetch different type of database. How can I fix this.  I have used the addValueEventListener 9 times to retrieve or sort different data stored at different nodes in the database. What would be the the proper of fetching the data. Any help would be appreciated. Here is some places I have used the code.

```
    firebaseUrl.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String temp, temp1;
            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: mytime " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
            long timeStampLong = (long) dataSnapshot.child("time").child("timestamp").getValue();
            SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

            temp1 = sfd.format(new Date(timeStampLong));
            try {
                if (isTimeBetweenTwoTime("08:00:00", "20:00:00", temp1)) {
                    //do something


                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    firebaseUrl.child("time").child("timestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

.

```
       DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String temp1;
                long timeStampLong = (long) dataSnapshot.child("time").child("timestamp").getValue();
                SimpleDateFormat sfd1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                temp1 = sfd1.format(new Date(timeStampLong));


                onClickShowAnswerButton(temp1);

            }

            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

.

```
public void onClickShowAnswerButton(String time) {

    try {
        if (isTimeBetweenTwoTime("08:00:00", "20:00:00", time)) {
            showDialogBox("Today's Answer", "The answer can be seen in between 8 PM to 8 AM only");
        } else {

            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String correctAnswerString, yourAnswerString;
                    String title;

                    correctAnswerString = dataSnapshot.child("questions").child(imagename).child("correctAnswer").getValue(String.class);
                    yourAnswerString = dataSnapshot.child("users").child(uid).child("questions").child(imagename).child("yourAnswer").getValue(String.class);
                    if (correctAnswerString.equals(yourAnswerString))
                        title = "CorrectAnswer: " + correctAnswerString + "\nCongratulations your answer answer is correct ";
                    else if (yourAnswerString == null)
                        title = "Answer: " + correctAnswerString + "\nYou haven't answered the question";
                    else
                        title = "Answer: " + correctAnswerString + "\nYour Answer: " + yourAnswerString + "\nSorry your answer is incorrect";

                    showDialogBox("Today's Answer", title);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Place some code in your question so we can see what's going on. It's hard to figure things out without reading what you've done so far.

Comment: have updated the question @rob.

Answer (score 0):

IMO what you should be doing is attaching the listener once, and then making that data available to your other methods, either through caching or persistent storage. You could create a data object that is updated when firebase is updated, and possibly use something like data binding to update the UI. But you only need to attach one listener, despite how many other places need the data. You can always get data once you have it.

Comment: Hey, I am new to this. Could you provide me some example or documentation that can be referred to resolve this @BlackHatSamurai

Answer (score 0):

Using SingleEventListener instead of ValueEventListener